# jQuery plugin jGrow not working

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have the following code, in which jGrow is not working.
I have included Javascript jGrow file. Textarea doesn't adjusts its size according to lengtht of text, instead a scrollbar appears in textarea

```
<html><head>
<title>jGrow</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jgrow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("textarea#sample1").jGrow({
max_height: "300px"
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form>
<textarea id="sample1">Jgrow</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's going wrong? What is the error, did you load the jgrow javascript file? Using the JGrow 0.4.0 version? Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried debugging with for example Firebux in Firefox?
I suspect jGrow hasn't been loaded yet before you are calling it. Solution is to wrap your call into `$(document).ready(function() {/* your code */});`

```
<html><head>
<title>jGrow</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jgrow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea#sample1").jGrow({
    max_height: "300px"
    });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form>
<textarea id="sample1">Jgrow</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i have wrapped my call into $(document).ready(function() {});, but still it is not working. When i clicked on respective jgrow.js from firebug it is not displaying anything, what may be the problem???

Comment: Does jgrow.js have an (error)code next to it in firebug? 200 is ok anything else means something wrong

Comment: No, it does not have any number next to it that means it is loaded properly??

Comment: Are you looking at the right page? You should look for the 'Net' tab. Each file downloaded has a status (code) and it should be 200(ok) or 304(not modified).